# Recreating Doodles Accordion Table

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In my current Webproject I have to implement a table containing all days of a month, resulting in ~30-31 table columns. Since such a huge table isn't very pretty, I wanted to implement something similar to the tables of Doodle Polls. Doodle folds a table, replaces the hidden columns with a pic and if you click on that picture it unfolds the columns -> displays the hidden columns.

But how do I achieve such a behaviour? I'm new to Javascript and not that familiar with fancy CSS3 techniques.

Especially, how do I replace the hidden columns with a picture?
The tutorials I've found only allow to hide specific columns and not to replace them.

PS: I also tagged RoR, since the project I'm working on is built with RoR and maybe there is also a Rails solution for that problem?

PPS:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could hide the columns you want to hide first and have a column with the image displayed in the table. When the image (folding) is clicked you can hide the column containing the picture and make the other columns visible again. This is not really about some fancy css3 stuff but you need basic knowledge of how to interact with DOM elements through javascript (hide / show) elements. That should do the trick.

See [this](http://www.w3schools.com/htmldom/) tutorial at w3schools. All that you need is get the elements you need (Image Column and all TDs in the hidden columns) ant then apply a css style to them (hidden / visible).